# How to create own OpenStreetMap tiles offline on Windows?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, offline

I want to create own OpenStreetMap tiles offline on Windows. I've downloaded czech-republic-latest.osm.pbf file at geofabrik.de site, however I am unable to load it to the MapSurfer.NET and Maperative due to /16 GB/ memory overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles).  There are many other approaches involving PostGIS and Geoserver KOSMOS and other tools that a search on this site will reveal.  If you have any questions on a specific approach, open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the .pbf file with osmconvert or osmosis, to fit the RAM limit you have hit.

Make sure to have some overlap to avoid missing features.